# Have the DOI be a link when using achemso?

Tags: hyperref, links, achemso

Is it possible to make the DOI into a link with achemso, as it is with biblatex-chem? I'm going to assume no, or that would be done already, but thought I'd check. I know I'd have to turn that option off before submitting it, but it is useful when editing the paper after a while, as then when I want to check out a specific reference I can just click the link instead of having to go hunting for it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to copy the achemso.bst file and place it in my latex document folder as achemso_edit.bst

Inspired by the rsc.bst file, I have commented the `format.doi` function in the achemso_edit.bst file

```
% FUNCTION { format.doi } {
%   doi empty$
%     'skip$
%     {
%       bbl.doi add.space
%       "\doi{" * doi * "}" *
%       output
%     }
%   if$
% }
```

and replaced it by

```
FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ ctrl.doi.bool
    { doi empty$
        'skip$
        {
          link.doi
            {
              "\href{http://dx.doi.org/"
              doi *
              "}{" *
              bbl.doi doi tie.or.space.connect *
              "}" *
            }
            { bbl.doi doi tie.or.space.connect }
          if$
          output
        }
      if$
    }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

To get this to work, some booleans are necessary.

I've added the `link.doi` boolean to the `INTEGERS` list

```
INTEGERS {
  ctrl.article.title.bool
  ctrl.chapter.title.bool
  ctrl.doi.bool
  ctrl.etal.firstonly.bool
  ctrl.etal.number.int
  link.doi
}
```

and enabled it in the `FUNCTIONS` list

```
FUNCTION { initialize.control.values } {
  #1 'link.doi :=
  #1 'ctrl.article.title.bool :=
  #0 'ctrl.chapter.title.bool :=
  #1 'ctrl.doi.bool :=
  #1 'ctrl.etal.firstonly.bool :=
  #15 'ctrl.etal.number.int :=
}
```

I've copied the complete achemso_edit.bst file to https://pastebin.com/5hZni8rb

The bibliography style is used by issuing the command before the `\bibliography` command

```
\bibliographystyle{achemso_edit.bst}
```